# How can I tell if I have Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010 installed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How can I tell if a computer has Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

I assume it is by version number, but I don't know what version means what. (The version I am looking at is **10.0.30319.1 RTMRel**.)

Comment: Referenced in *[Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Site Lesson 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8f5rKmVtng)*.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

When you have SP1 installed you'll see instead:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel
```

Therefore you are still on RTM (release to market) version, not the SP.

Answer (score 18):

RTMRel is the "[release to manufacturing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#RTM)" release. This is when the product is officially launched. If you have SP1 installed, it would say "SP1Rel" after the version (in the case of Visual Studio).