# How can I check if SP1 is installed on my Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

How can I check if SP1 is installed on my Visual Studio 2010?

I can't find it in the About screen.

---

[image]

For example in Visual Studio 2005:

On the left I don't see any service pack, but in the right pane I see SP2 of the framework.

Is it the same? Is there's a service pack for the framework and another for Visual Studio? Or only one service pack for the framework?

Comment: Then you've probably not got it installed!

Comment: The version of the framework and the version of visual studio are generally independent. It's possible to have .NET 2.0 SP2 with no instances of Visual Studio installed for example.

Comment: duplicate of [How can I tell if I have Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010 installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850352/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-service-pack-1-for-visual-studio-2010-installed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Help` -> `About`.

The version of the installation will be SP1Rel if SP1 is installed.

[image: SP1]

Comment: @mid787 please don't post edits as answers, edit the main question

Answer (score 0):

In my About box in Visual Studio 2010 I see *"Version 10.... SP1Rel"* in the second row on the left.