# What does "RTMREL" mean in software versioning?

Tags: versioning, visual-studio-2012

I just installed Visual Studio 2012 and noticed that the version as mentioned in the 'about' menu is:

`Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL`

I am familiar with `RTM` (Release To Manufacturing) but am curious what the `REL` component means.

Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RTMRel is the ["release to manufacturing" *release*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850413/14955). A bit redundant, but rhymes with "SP1Rel" (the Service Pack 1 release).

Update: see Edward's comment below. There is a point to the "Rel" part. It means a "release" build (optimized and stripped of debugging information). MSDN members can also get "Chk" builds for debugging purposes.

Comment: Actually, the *REL* in this case is the *type* of build.  Internally, we have two build types:  *REL* builds are "release" builds, which are built with optimizations, and *CHK* builds which are "debug" builds that include no optimizations and debugging symbols.  If you have MSDN you should be able to find an RTM CHK build!

Answer (score 0):

According to this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0db1059-6006-4e9a-8d82-6508adef31e0/is-it-the-rtm-or-final-version-of-visual-studio-2012-?forum=vssetup

> RTM means Release to Manufacturing, i.e. the image that goes on DVD's in retail boxes