# How to tell if you have service pack 1 and 2 installed on Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

How can I discover if service packs 1 and 2 have been installed for Visual Studio 2012? I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

This link: [How can I tell if I have Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850352/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-service-pack-1-for-visual-studio-2010-installed) shows how to do it on 2010. Following the same premises my version is shown as:

Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL

But not 100% sure what that means.

My question is different from the one above because thats for vs 2010. And looking at the answers and my version number listed above, it clearly shows the version number patters are different for the two products so it doesnt apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell if I have Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010 installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850352/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-service-pack-1-for-visual-studio-2010-installed)

Comment: Please see update to question to show how I dont think it is

Comment: They call them "Updates" now.  You would see something like "Update 4" next to the version number.

Comment: So my version number signifies I dont even have service pack 1 installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a screen shot of my VS 2012, with Update 4.  It appears your version is the released version with no updates installed.

[image]